# richfaces datatable and radio button, radio button not working then page is changed

Tags: jsf, datatable, radio-button, richfaces

I used JSF1.2 with richfaces, I have datatable with radio button, and after click on radio button, it must be send object id to bean, it is working but when I change the page, after click no action..

```
   <h:selectOneRadio onclick="radioButton(this);" value="#{documentLinkManagementController.updatedDocParamId}" 
                                              valueChangeListener="#{documentLinkManagementController.setSelected}">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{documentParamViewBean.id}"/>    
                                <a4j:support event="onchange" actionListener="#{documentLinkManagementController.initUpdate}">
                                    <a4j:actionparam value="#{documentParamViewBean.id}" assignTo="#{documentLinkManagementController.updatedDocParamId}"/>                                            
                                </a4j:support> 
                            </h:selectOneRadio>        


        <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[                 
            function radioButton(radio) {
                var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
                var el = radio.form.elements;
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
                        el[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
                radio.checked = true;
            }
//]]>                                      
        </script>
```

what is the problem? Actually in JSF1.2 datatable with radio button working with java script help, I show also  it. But after changing the page, action and action listeners with radio button not working:(((((

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing a4j:support to primefaces p:ajax,